# What does 幸せボケ mean?

Tags: meaning, nuances

I've seen a movie described as 幸せボケした映画

What is the exact nuance of  幸せボケ? Some google search suggest it is a king to "shallow happiness"?

Answer (score 4):

It's not a common set phrase, so it's hard to give a definitive answer without sufficient context. Is this from a movie review or something?

In general, ボケ refers to mental haziness due to various reasons such as aging (i.e. dementia) and jet lag (時差ボケ). 平和ボケ is used to critically describe a situation where people have been in peace for such a long time that they are no longer aware of the importance of peace or become less vigilant about threats.

By extension, 幸せボケ (lit. "happiness haziness") might refer to a situation where people are happy for such a long time that they forget to appreciate how happy they are. Alternatively, it might refer to a situation where someone is so happy that they don't pay attention to other important elements of life such as labor. Since it modifies 映画, the latter interpretation may be more likely; it could be a movie that focuses too much about someone's happiness and neglects realistic depiction. However, the actual meaning could depend on the context.

Comment: Yes, it's a review/criticism of a movie.